# Write a non-recursive algorithm to compute n factorial

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am having problems writing a code in java to compute n! without recursion. I know how to do it in loops, but I am not sure how to do it non-recursively.

```
procedure factorial

if n = 1 or n = 0
return 1
if n>1
return(n*factorial(n-1))
end
```

Comment: Loop is not recursion.

Comment: Example you have given is not not using loops

Comment: It's also not valid Java.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an iterative solution:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    int f = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        f *= i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Good answer to a bad question, +1

Comment: Thanks! I'm not exactly sure what the question was asking, but I tried...

Comment: You should avoid using `int` as the return value, it will overflow very quickly use a `long`, or even better a `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: @amit I disagree. Generally you want to return a primative, and int's are used a lot more than longs. You could write another method called "longFactorial" but...

Comment: No problem, it was an excellent start. As for using `BigInteger`, I echo that sentiment because it loses accurate results around 60! even when using `long`

Comment: If you return a `long` java can convert it to `int` easily if you assign the return value to an `int`, using a simple cast. I'd still use a `BigInteger` anyway, but that's arguable. There is no real downside to using a `long` however.